# SSRS - Can I have alternate parameters?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

In a report (SSRS 2008R2), I want to have two parameters: a checkbox and a dropdown list. However, if checkbox is checked, I want to disable dropdown list and vice versa. Is it possible? How?
Thanks.

Comment: You could have your dropdownlist filled depending on the checkbox value. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345870/enable-disable-ssrs-parameters) is a full example

Comment: You cannot disable/enable parameters based on user interaction.   They are set at design time.   Maybe there's another way to achieve the overall effect that you want.

Comment: @TabAlleman: i agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you cant have a checkbox as a parameter.  For a boolean value, you'll have to use true/false radio buttons.

Having said that, you can still achieve what you need with a bit of a kludge

Use the boolean value as a parameter to the DataSet that returns the values for Drop Down, if the boolean value is set, have the script that populates the checkbox return nothing, else have the script return the expected values.

eg

```
if @check = 1
    select  id=-1
            ,Name='Nothing to Select'
else
    select  id
            ,Name 
    from MyTable
```

Comment: the person wants to hide or show the parameter based on another parameter which is not possible in SSRS. There is no tweeking also to hide the parameter As per my knowledge

Comment: The question actually states to how to disable (rather than hide/show).  Although this solution is a kludge and may not work for for the OP, it does _effectively_ **disable** the drop down using cascading parameters by removing all options from the drop down.  Again maybe not useful, but it may give the OP some ideas to work with.